# Is it possible that we can remove comma from character variable by R command?

Tags: r

I have a table column names and variables contain comma eg. "Stark, Tony". How could I remove comma from all row by using R command?

Comment: To learn `?gsub` function

Comment: I'm happy to answer this question, but it also feels like something you could have found for yourself with a little bit of effort.  Googling "R remove character from string" gets lots of useful hits.

Answer (score 3):

```r
stringr::str_remove("Stark, Tony", ",")
## [1] "Stark Tony"
```

or in base R

```r
gsub(",", "", "Stark, Tony")
```